# Unable to Profile data in Oracle (OAC) DV dataset section

Tags: oracle-analytics-cloud

When we create a dataset, data profiling is done by Oracle automatically
and then we can see the complete dataset.

My OAC is failing to profile the data, and shows me an error.

I was expecting that data will be profiled automatically so that I can work on my workbook quickly..

profiling error screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLOWO.png